# How does it works the Laravel 4 model relationships?

Tags: php, laravel

I wish to know how works the laravel 4 relationships in the model. This question is because i'm trying to get the rows from 2 tables with relation and not success till now.

```
class Products extends Eloquent {

protected $table = "Products";
protected $primaryKey = "ProductId";

public function plandetail()
{
        return $this->belongsTo("PlanDetail", "PlanDetail.ProductId")->select( array("ProductId", "Order") );
}

public function getProductsPlan($dealerId)
{
    return $this->with( "plandetail" )->where("Products.DealerId", $dealerId)->get();
}
} // end model

// In my controller

$product = new Products();
$products = $product->getProductsPlan($id);

foreach( $products as $product )
{
     print_r($product); // prints only the rows from the Products table
                        // not the PlanDetail table.
}
```

In the output is just print the product records and not the PlanDetail table rows. Do i need to add a join with the PlanDetail table to get these rows?

This is one example row of what im getting now:

```
Products Object ( [table:protected] => Products [primaryKey:protected] => ProductId [errors:Products:private] => [rules:Products:private] => Array ( [ProductBaseId] => required|numeric [DealerId] => required|numeric [ProductName] => required|max:255 [DisplayName] => required|max:255 [Bullets] => required [Cost] => required|numeric [SellingPrice] => required|numeric [UseWebServicePricing] => required|boolean [Term] => required|numeric [Type] => required|numeric [Deductible] => required|numeric [VehiclePlan] => required|numeric [Mileage] => required|numeric [TireRotation] => required|numeric [Interval] => required|numeric [UseRangePricing] => required|boolean [IsTaxable] => required|boolean [NotRegulated] => required|boolean [CreatedOn] => required [CreatedBy] => required [ModifiedBy] => required [ModifiedOn] => required ) [connection:protected] => [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [timestamps] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [ProductId] => 3 [ProductBaseId] => 84 [DealerId] => 50 [ProductName] => Vehicle Service Contract [DisplayName] => US Warranty Service Contract [ProductDescription] => [Bullets] => Warranty Proteccion for the covered components,Rental Car Coverage,Towling Coverage,, [Cost] => 0.0 [SellingPrice] => 0.0 [BrochureImage] => [PDFContrator] => [UseWebServicePricing] => 1 [UseManualPricing] => 0 [BrochureHeight] => 0 [BrochureWidth] => 0 [Term] => 36 [Type] => Platinum [Deductible] => 100 [VehiclePlan] => None [Mileage] => 36000 [TireRotation] => 0 [Interval] => 0 [PENProductId] => 0 [DMSProductId] => 16 [CreatedBy] => GREIVIN BRITTON [CreatedOn] => 2015-01-08 22:26:47.000 [UseRangePricing] => 0 [ModifiedBy] => GREIVIN BRITTON [ModifiedOn] => 2015-01-28 15:06:11.000 [IsTaxable] => 0 [NotRegulated] => 0 ) [original:protected] => Array ( [ProductId] => 3 [ProductBaseId] => 84 [DealerId] => 50 [ProductName] => Vehicle Service Contract [DisplayName] => US Warranty Service Contract [ProductDescription] => [Bullets] => Warranty Proteccion for the covered components,Rental Car Coverage,Towling Coverage,, [Cost] => 0.0 [SellingPrice] => 0.0 [BrochureImage] => [PDFContrator] => [UseWebServicePricing] => 1 [UseManualPricing] => 0 [BrochureHeight] => 0 [BrochureWidth] => 0 [Term] => 36 [Type] => Platinum [Deductible] => 100 [VehiclePlan] => None [Mileage] => 36000 [TireRotation] => 0 [Interval] => 0 [PENProductId] => 0 [DMSProductId] => 16 [CreatedBy] => GREIVIN BRITTON [CreatedOn] => 2015-01-08 22:26:47.000 [UseRangePricing] => 0 [ModifiedBy] => GREIVIN BRITTON [ModifiedOn] => 2015-01-28 15:06:11.000 [IsTaxable] => 0 [NotRegulated] => 0 ) [relations:protected] => Array ( [plandetail] => ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [fillable:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [with:protected] => Array ( ) [morphClass:protected] => [exists] => 1 [softDelete:protected] => )
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a few things wrong here.

The `belongsTo` method expects the name of the relating model, and then the foreign key of that model on the `Products` table.  It looks like your foreign key is actually on the relating model making this relationship either a `hasOne` or `hasMany`.  In this case, since you say you are expecting 2 rows, I'm assuming `hasMany`.

Additionally, the second argument of this only expects the name of the column.  It can already guess the name of the table because you gave it the relating model name.

With that in mind, this should be the relationship method you need.

```
public function plandetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany("PlanDetail", "ProductId")->select( array("ProductId", "Order") );
}
```

And the other function should be modified a bit.  When you use `with` and you need to query based on the relation, you should pass in an array where the key is the name of the relation and the value is a callback function which will allow you to modify the query which will grab the relating items.

```
public function getProductsPlan($dealerId)
{
    return $this->with(array("plandetail", function($q) use ($dealerId)
    {
        $q->where('DealerID', $dealerId);
    }))->get();
}
```

Now when you do this...

```
$product = new Products();
$products = $product->getProductsPlan($id);
```

This should work...

```
foreach( $products as $product ) {
    foreach($product->plandetails as $plandetail) {
        print_r($plandetail);
    }
}
```

I also modified the relating function name so you would have to update your `getProductsPlan` function to reflect that when you use `with`.  When you use `hasMany`, it makes more sense and is easier to read when you make the function name plural.

Comment: It works but when i added this in the get it fails: `return $this->with( "plandetail" )->where("Products.DealerId", $dealerId)->get( array( DB::raw("CAST(ISNULL(PlanDetail.ProductId, 0) AS BIT) AS Added") ) );` get this result: `'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "PlanDetail.ProductId" could not be bound. (SQL: select CAST(ISNULL(PlanDetail.ProductId, 0) AS BIT) AS Added from [Products] where [Products].[DealerId] = 50)'`

Comment: Sorry, forgot one thing.  I've added the new `getProductsPlan` function.